# PHP isset does not seem to read correctly in processing

Tags: php, isset

I'm having a weird thing occur in a PHP script I'm writing. I have a rather large form with a lot of fields, checkboxes, radio buttons, etc.

In the processing script there is a lot of repetitious code where I check to see if a field isset and if it is then it outputs a sentence based on that field.

The code I use to process the field is:

```
if(isset($_POST['testresults'])) { // test results Info
    $testresults = $_POST['testresults'];
    echo $clientInitials . " test results are " . $testresults . ". ";
}
```

Now, for some reason, of the 40+ blocks that are identical to this (only with different variables and sentence output) there are two that execute even when the field is empty/not set. As a test, I copied the same block of code to a new PHP file and it has the same behavior, but this is an exact copy of a block that works properly except for the field/variable name. I've cut-n-pasted the field name from the form to make sure there wasn't a spelling mistake or something.
As another test, if I change the line to if(!isset($_POST['testresults'])) then it skips that block like it should. So it is reacting as if there is data in that field even when there is not (and it does this with 1 other block as well). The field names/variables are also not used anywhere else in the script and I verified this through doing a search on the file.

The form field is:

```
<input type="text" name="testresults" value="">
```

I've tried it with and without the "value" parameter with no change. All the other ones that work correctly have value="" in them.

I've tried clearing my browser cache and there is no difference, still does this odd behavior.

So I guess I'm just wondering if there is a limit to using isset(), or am I missing something?

Comment: PHP's functions don't care how many times they might be called during execution of a script, there are no usage caps, so your problem is something else.... beware empty != not set

Comment: Though why you're creating 40 almost duplicate blocks of code, I don't know.... surely creating a function that you can call in a loop is better

Comment: isset() will return true even if it is empty, so if the form is sending nothing then isset() will still return true, you might want to try `if(isset($_POST["testresults"]) && !empty($_POST["testresults"])){//code}`

Comment: You don't need `isset()` if you are using `!empty()`. You can just use `if(!empty($_POST["testresults"])) { ...etc`

Comment: Can't believe I didn't know that already, cheers :p

Comment: Made an answer instead of a comment so it can be marked as solved. (Assuming it is)

Comment: Chris and Rasclatt, thank you. That solved the problem. Mark, the reason is because each field generates unique output, so even though that little block is duplicated over and over it would actually be far more difficult and complex to make a function that actually works. This solution is actually much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isset()` will only check if a value is set, and not if it is empty, which is why it's more commonly used to check if a form is actually submitted in the first place, or to check $_GET variables. The function you should be using is `empty()` - or in your case `!empty()` like so:

```
if(!empty($_POST['testresults'])) { // test results Info
    $testresults = $_POST['testresults'];
    echo $clientInitials . " test results are " . $testresults . ". ";
}
```